# Is is possible to hide the menu bar in full screen on only external monitors of a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, menu-bar

With MacBook Pro 2021 model, I want to keep the menu bar visible even in full screen, as that part of display is not used by the application anyway. But with external monitors, I want to let them automatically hide the menu bar for maximum space usage. Is this setting possible to achieve currently?

From what I've learned, I can let menu bars on all monitors automatically hide in full screen, or completely disable menu bars on external monitors. But there seems to be no way to auto hide menu bars only on external monitors.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change this setting per app. Not exactly what you're asking for, but maybe it helps.

```
defaults write com.example.SomeApp AppleMenuBarVisibleInFullscreen -bool true
```

To revert

```
defaults delete com.example.SomeApp AppleMenuBarVisibleInFullscreen
```

Replace com.example.SomeApp with the bundle identifier of the app you want to apply this to, to figure out what the bundle identifier is you can for example do osascript -e 'id of app "TextEdit"' which would give you com.apple.TextEdit.

If you have the option on in system preferences you can also do the opposite, replace true in the above command with false and the menu bar will again auto-hide for that specific app.

You may need to restart the specific app after writing the defaults.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/pamaob/you_can_set_the_new_show_menu_bar_in_full_screen/)